# Google Maps SDK Logo Options

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps

I'm developing a tab bar view application on IOS with swift. I'm integrating Google Maps SDK, however the bottom section of my map is tucked under the tab bar area. This hides the Google Logo which is against the policy of Google. Is there a way to specify the map to start directly above the tab bar area? Additionally, does anyone know if the logo can be ethically removed through paid services with Google? In other words, is there a "premium" membership with google that could remove the logo?

This is how my mapview is constructed currently:

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.camera(withLatitude: 40.000, longitude: -83.000, zoom: 12)
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect.zero, camera: camera)
view = mapView
```

Comment: please mark the answer to accept it.

Comment: The logo may be removed, but you have to contact them to purchase the contents directly. From the [attribution guide](https://www.google.com/permissions/geoguidelines/attr-guide.html): "Do I need to use the text provided on the imagery?

The automatically generated Google logo and data provider attribution may only be removed or obstructed if reintroduced in a visible form elsewhere within the Content (e.g. photo caption below a Google Earth still). In other words, your text must be as visible as it would have been if you had used the default text that we provide."

Comment: Or according to the [sdk doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/map#map_padding): "Note: As specified in the Google Maps APIs Terms of Service, your application must not remove or obscure the Google logo or copyright notices. Map Padding allows you to reposition these elements if necessary. If you display a custom UI at the bottom of the map, add padding to the bottom of the map so that the logo and legal notices will always be visible."

Answer (score 1):

To position the map so that the tab bar isn't covering it, you could do something like this:

```
let mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:self.view.bounds.width, height:self.view.bounds.height - self.tabBarController!.tabBar.frame.height), camera: camera)
self.view.addSubview(mapView)
```

Note the difference in the pic below. The left one is obscured by the tab bar (using your code), and the right one is my code. Instead of making the entire view the map, I'm adding the map as a subview with the dimensions of the area above the tab bar.

[image]

Regarding paying to omit the Google logo, it's an interesting question and I have no clue either, but I kind of doubt they would allow that because their brand is their bread-and-butter.

Comment: Thank you so much. Very helpful. I still don't know how this website works but I can't upvote your answer...

Comment: @BenjaminKrium, I think you click the grey checkmark under the arrows? But no worries either way, it was a fun challenge to figure out. I mostly work with the built-in Apple map, so it was interesting to see how the Google map SDK works differently.